# Replacing characters at start/end of string with PHP's ltrim/rtrim

Tags: php, trim

I am looking to clean whitespace and hyphen characters from the start/end of a string.

I have the following test code:

```
  $sample_titles = array(
    '— — -Daisy Chain –',
    'Ocarina for a Mermaid –',
    ' –—Another for a Sailor - '
  );

  foreach ( $sample_titles as $title ) {

    $updated_title = ltrim( $title, ' -–—' );
    $updated_title = rtrim( $updated_title, ' -–—' );

    echo $updated_title . '<br/>';

  }
```

This correctly outputs:

```
Daisy Chain
Ocarina for a Mermaid
Another for a Sailor
```

However, when I apply the same ltrim/rtrim logic in a foreach loop (over post titles, I'm "cleaning" imported data, the rest of the code is irrelevant) like this:

```
  foreach ( $product_ids as $key => $product_id ) {

    $title = get_the_title( $product_id );

    $updated_title = ltrim( $title, ' -–—' );
    $updated_title = rtrim( $updated_title, ' -–—' );

    echo $updated_title . '<br/>';

  };
```

I still end up with the hyphens/dashes/whitespace like this:

```
Orb 3 –
Ocarina for a Mermaid –
Mini Marina –
```

Any ideas why this works in one context but not the other?

Comment: if you're trimming the same characters from the beginning and end, just use `trim()` instead of `rtrim()` and `ltrim()`.

Comment: As for why it's not working, there must be something else after the spaces and hyphens when you call `get_the_title()`. Maybe a non-breaking space, or newline.

Comment: Try `echo ord($title[strlen($title)-1]);`

Comment: Or better: `echo mb_ord(mb_substr($title, mb_strlen($title)-1, 1));`

Comment: _Side note:_ The second argument to `trim()` is a list of characters to remove, not what string to remove so it's enough to add any character only once. This means that `' ---'` will have the same effect as just `' -'`. It will trim away all spaces and dashes, no matter how many or in what order they are.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks, but those are a hyphen, en dash and em dash- it's not just 3 hyphens. I'll review shortly.

Comment: @Barmar @MagnusEriksson thanks for pointing me in the right direction, wrapping my `get_the_title` in `html_entity_decode` fixed my issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrapping the title grab function in html_entity_decode() fixed the issue I was having:

```
$product_title = html_entity_decode( get_the_title( $product_id ) );
```